# Making a graph class iterate using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iterator

I am trying to build a iterable graph class with python 2.7. I want  to be able to iterate though a dictionary containing the vertexes.

Cutting and pasting from    https://github.com/joeyajames  has got me so far but  now  I am confused as to how  to make this work so that 
I can test vertices dict for  the presence of an vertice and  add if not present. This part is maybe unneeded.
"if (a not in gra ):" because the validation is done in the Graph class itself.

The expected output is a dictionary with the vertices as keys. Actualy im not even sure a list is not better object to use.

```
class Vertex(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
        self.neighbors = list()

        self.discovery = 0
        self.finish = 0
        self.color = 'black'

    def add_neighbor(self, v):
        if v not in self.neighbors:
            self.neighbors.append(v)
            self.neighbors.sort()


class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.vertices = {}
        self.hops = 0
        self.count = 0
        self.limit = size

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count > self.limit:
            raise StopIteration


    def add_vertex(self,vertex):
        if isinstance(vertex, Vertex) and vertex.name not in self.vertices:
            self.vertices[vertex.name] = vertex
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def add_edge(u,v):
        if u in self.vertices and v in self.vertices:
            for key, value in self.vertices.items():
                if key == u:
                    value.add_neighbor(v)
                if key == v:
                    value.add_neighbor(u)
                    return True
                else:
                    return False



    def _dfs(self, vertex):
            global hops
            vertex.color = 'red'
            vertex.discovery = hops
            hops += 1
            for v in vertex.neighbors:
                if self.vertices[v].color == 'black':
                    self._dfs(self.vertices[v])
            vertex.color = 'blue'
            vertex.finish = hops
            time += 1






input = ((5,3),(4 ,2),(0,1),(2 3),(0 4))

N,l = input[0]
print "N is " + str(N)
print "l is " + str(l)

gra = Graph(N)

for i in xrange(1,l):
    a,b = input[i]
    # Store a and b as vertices in graph object
    print "a is " + str(a) +  " b is " + str(b) 
    if (a not in gra ):
        print "adding a"
        gra.add_vertex(Vertex(chr(a)))
    if (b not in gra ):
        print "adding b"
        gra.add_vertex(Vertex(chr(b)))
```

Comment: Containment testing and iteration are *two separate things*. Your `next()` method also doesn't produce anything when iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `not in`, which tests for *containment*; implement the [`__contains__` hook](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) to facilitate that:

```
def __contains__(self, vertex):
    return vertex.name in self.vertices
```

I've assumed you wanted to test for vertices, so create one before testing for containment:

```
a = Vertex(chr(a))
if a not in gra:
    print "adding a"
    gra.add_vertex(a)
```

For iteration, I'd not make `Graph` itself the iterator; that limits you to iterating *just once*. Your `next()` method also lacks a `return` statement, so all you are doing is produce a sequence of `None` objects.

Make it an *iterable* instead, so return a new iterator object each time `__iter__` is called. You can most simply achieve this by making `__iter__` a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators):

```
def __iter__(self):
    for vertex in self.vertices.itervalues():
        yield vertex
```

Note the `yield`. I've assumed you wanted to iterate over the vertices.